# Creating an array of numbers to use in a pickerview not working

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a pickerview tied to a textbox that i'm trying to fill with a range of numbers, 48-96.  I don't want to type them all out so i'm using the below:
`var height = Array(48...96)`

but i get the below error:
Cannot convert return expression of type 'Int' to return type 'String?'

I've tried the below but it doesn't work so i'm helping you kind folks could help:
`var height = String(Array(48...96))`

I expect to be able to use an array and convert it to a string versus having to type our 48, 49, 50...96 but cant figure out how to convert the array of ints to strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an array of `String` containing `"48"` through `"96"`.  You can do that by using `map` on a range:

```
var height = (48...96).map(String.init)

print(height)
```

> ["48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96"]